# Related articles popup with Entity Reference View Widget

Tags: 8

For the Articles, I have added below field.

```
Related Articles -> field_related_articles  -> Entity reference
```

So it's view like this
[image]

Now it's not very user friendly. So I want to create Popup where user can search & select articles.

https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget

I found above, but it's not supporting Drupal 8.

Anyone have idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Field Widget]

1) You can change the field widget for the form display at yoursite/admin/structure/types/manage/article/form-display.

2)You could check this out for a combination of inline entity form and entity browser modules https://github.com/drupal-media/d8-guide/blob/master/modules/entity_browser/inline_entity_form.md
[image: Entity Browser]
3) If you choose 1) and you change the field widget to a dropdown select list, you can also use the "chosen" module https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen for a better user experience

Comment: Thanks for answer. I would like to give user listing & search